# drupal_http_post redirect

Tags: 7

I am currently experimenting with drupal_http_request to send my users information to a payment service - there is more configuration to be done so it is not working yet.

When I do get it successfully POSTing users details, it is important that the user is redirected to the payment service.

**Can anyone tell me if drupal_http_request does redirect as it POSTs data?**

If it doesn't I would appreciate suggestions on how I can achieve simultaneous POSTing and redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use `drupal_http_request()`.

```
$options = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => 'name=Test&email=example...',
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
);

$result = drupal_http_request('http://example.com', $options);
```

In `$result`, you will get an object with the data of the request. 
Check the `$result` object and make sure the payment is gone through (or whatever the condition that should pass before redirecting the user).

Then, use [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) to redirect the user to the new location.

Note that this is just a normal redirect (GET) and data is already submitted to the Payment server by your site.

If you want to use Paypal IPN-like requests that the **user** POSTs data to the server, you need to create a form instead.

```
function _test_payment_form() {
  $form = array();

  $form['user'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#name-info' => 'user', // this is the field name that will become name attribute of the input tag. No need to use this if your $form['KEY'] is same as this one. 
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('Proceed to @server for the payment', array('@server' => 'Paypal')),
  );

  $form['#action'] = 'http://example-payment-server.com/example/2/3/4'; // Information will now be submitted to this URL other than Drupal. 
  $form['#method'] = 'POST', // Just for clarification. This is the default value. 

   return $form;
}
```

You can print the form using the following code.

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('_test_payment_form'));
```

You can also use the following code, where render arrays are accepted.

```
drupal_get_form('_test_payment_form');
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. The primary issue for me is the automation of customer re-direction to the payment system. My concern is if the POSTing of authentication data and re-directing the user can be successfully handled separately. I will let you know